# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error Pagebuilder in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

when i try to access page builder page in my wordpress admin console it shows an
“MY DOMAIN NAME showed here” didn’t send any data.ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
I tried with all browsers and deactivated all plugins, but nothing works. i used concord theme.

Because of this issue i can't update my website.

[image]

Comment: this would be (90% of the time) a plugin conflict. can you list active plugins, wp version, active themes and from there i can troubleshoot you.

Comment: hi,, i added the image for plugin details and error details

Comment: you are using a fairly dated wordpress install. are you sure your theme is designed for this version? and make a checklist of minimal wordpress versions for all active plugins.

Comment: Yes...It is working fine till last week.

Comment: well if a list of all plugin versions and minimal wordpress installs cannot be posted, all i can tell you is to deactivate all non-essential plugins, see if it works and then reactivating one at a time testing in between. perhaps copy your site to a dev environement and run updates on your theme/wp/plugins one at a time, and see if it will fix it. its a bit of a voodoo science. also, you could try enabling error display (in you php.ini or in your wordpress config file), it would allow a more educated guess.

Comment: dump this in your wp-config file
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // enable or disable php error logging (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('error_log','/home/userName/logs/php-errors.log'); // path to server-writable log file

be sure to create the file for logs (anywhere, as long as you use that path in the config) and make it writable

Answer (score 0):

Update word press,plugin,theme (Don't forget to keep backup)

http://user.successfulpeoplestories.com/guest-blog-post/wordpress/how-to-fix-wordpress-blank-page-errors-and-similar-issues/

Comment: This answer requires expansion.  Consider being more specific about what to update and fix.